# How to read null number using SimpleJdbcCall in Java, Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with SimpleJdbcCall. There is a null value in a number column and when i'm trying to query it through stored procedure i got NumberFormatException.

I have a table that has this structure:

```
 COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE
 -----------------------------
 USER_ID        NUMBER
 LOGIN          VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
 PASSWORD       VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)
 NAME           VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
 RATING         NUMBER(1,1)
```

There is one record that i'm trying to query:

```
USER_ID    LOGIN        PASSWORD        NAME            RATING
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          TestLogin    TestPassword    TestName        null
```

This is my procedure:

```
create or replace procedure get_user_by_login

                               (p_login in number,
                                p_password out varchar2,
                                p_name out varchar2,
                                p_rating out number)
  as

  begin

    select password, name, rating
      into p_password, p_name, p_rating
      from users_test
      where login = p_login;

  end;
/
```

This is my code:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = getUserByLogin("TestLogin");

        System.out.println(user);
    }



    static User getUserByLogin(String login)
    {
        SimpleJdbcCall          call = new SimpleJdbcCall(getDataSource());
                                call.withProcedureName("get_user_by_login");

        MapSqlParameterSource   in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
                                in.addValue("p_login", login);

        call.declareParameters( new SqlOutParameter("p_password", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("p_name", Types.VARCHAR),
                                new SqlOutParameter("p_rating", Types.NUMERIC));

        Map<String, Object> out = call.execute(in);

        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPassword((String) out.get("p_password"));
        user.setName((String) out.get("p_name"));
        user.setRating((BigDecimal) out.get("p_rating"));

        return user;
    }

    static DataSource getDataSource() {
        PoolProperties poolProps = new PoolProperties();
        poolProps.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:testDB");
        poolProps.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        poolProps.setUsername("TestUser");
        poolProps.setPassword("test");
        poolProps.setInitialSize(5);
        poolProps.setMaxActive(10);

        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setPoolProperties(poolProps);

        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

This is exception i'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:494)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8954)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9557)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:6090)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:249)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:364)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCreatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:405)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:365)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:198)
    at com.eisima.spring.Main.getUserByLogin(Main.java:39)
    at com.eisima.spring.Main.main(Main.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: It sounds like the data in your DB for column `RATING` isnt a number. Check the data in your DB and ensure its a number.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can approach this situation many ways, like for example, although this isn't the most optimal way to do it:

```
try {
   user.setRating((BigDecimal) out.get("p_rating"));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or maybe:

```
if (out.get("p_rating") == null) {
  user.setRating(new BigDecimal(0));
}
```

But if you're trying to put a null value you should expect `NumberFormatException`. One of the two above will solve your problem but you should analyze your use case to see what will actually be the best for you.

Comment: The stack trace points to it occurring inside the JDBC driver not when getting the rating.

Comment: `RATING` is a number as OP states `RATING NUMBER(1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason was in incorrect procedure declaration:

```
    create or replace procedure get_user_by_login

 -- i'm passing string there --->  (p_login in number, 
                                    p_password out varchar2,
                                    p_name out varchar2,
                                    p_rating out number)
      as

      begin

        select password, name, rating
          into p_password, p_name, p_rating
          from users
          where login = p_login;

      end;
    /
```

I was thinking the error in converting null to BigDecimal, but there wasn't any errors with null values at all. Procedure call, as expected, returns null value when value in column is null.

Thanks to everybody for help.